# Paste Filepath via White UI \ is printed as ß

Tags: c#, encoding, automation

I am working on a White UI automatisation program.

My current step in the automation process is to "paste" a systempath to a file I want to open.

```
mainWindow.Keyboard.Enter("C:\\Folder\\File.jpg");
```

Pastes this String to the GUI but instead of \ it prints a ß

same when using

```
\u005c as enconding for \\
```

There must be some kind of enconding error. System where program is executed operates Win 7 32bit.

**Quickfix**

The Quickfix for this problem is to take US as standard keyboard layout. Since there seems to be a problem with the White UI Keyboard.Enter(String) implementation regarding special chars in other languages.

Comment: Whenever I change Windows locale to Japanese, I get ¥ instead of \, so I guess it's got something to do with your locale.

Comment: Could be the locale or the white Ui implementation of Keyboard.Enter i am not quite shure yet, i try to change keyboard layout to US

Comment: Typing a backslash on a German keyboard layout is difficult, it requires pressing the AltGr dead key first.  Programs that emulate keystrokes always falter on that, they cannot inject the state of dead keys easily.